# Calling Procs from CASE statement in PL/SQL Block : issue faced

Tags: oracle, plsql, case, block, procedure

I have created following Block which asksthe user to choose the option.
Each option then calls the stored procedure to process the information received ( whether balance to be showed or deposit , withdrawal to be made for particular id.

```
`set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  V_CHOICE NUMBER(1)  := &V_CHOICE;
  ID       NUMBER(5)  := &ID;
  AMT      NUMBER(20) := &AMT;
BEGIN
  CASE V_CHOICE
  WHEN 1 THEN
    EXEC SHOW_BALANCE(ID);
  WHEN 2 THEN
    EXEC DEPOSITS (ID ,AMT);
  WHEN 3 THEN
    EXEC WITHDRAWAL (ID, AMT);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Invalid choice');
  END CASE;
END;
/`
```

Each of these procedure can be executed individually by passing on the respective parameter , however while using case statement I am getting PL/SQL compilation errors

```
 Error report:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SHOW_BALANCE" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "SHOW_BALANCE" to continue.
```

Kindly advice whats wrong with the PL/SQL block.

Comment: EXEC is a SQL\*Plus command not a PL/SQL one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `EXEC`:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  V_CHOICE NUMBER(1)  := &V_CHOICE;
  ID       NUMBER(5)  := &ID;
  AMT      NUMBER(20) := &AMT;
BEGIN
  CASE V_CHOICE
  WHEN 1 THEN        SHOW_BALANCE(ID);
  WHEN 2 THEN        DEPOSITS(ID ,AMT);
  WHEN 3 THEN        WITHDRAWAL(ID, AMT);
  ELSE               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid choice');
  END CASE;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much lad2025 .